# All signs of clutch slipping but the car only has 48,000 miles. How can this be?

Tags: clutch, wear

I have a 10 yr old fiat panda with 38k miles on the odometer. Manual Transmission. Within couple months I started getting all of the symptoms of the clutch slipping. The condition is worse in a higher gear.  I have only put 10K miles on it.

Why has the clutch gone so quickly with only a total of 48K miles on the vehicle?

Answer (score 4):

There are two likely possibilities, and it could be both:

**Abuse**

As described in James' answer, with the right owner a clutch could be decimated with relatively low mileage. With mileage that low it would take some serious abuse to get there.

**Low Quality**

The clutch may have been built with low quality components. The Scion xA and xB of the mid 2000's used inferior pressure plate springs. As a result they could weaken quickly and clutch slipping became common even below 10k in some cases. A little Google searching suggests that the Fiat Panda *might* have a similar issue. I drove my sister's xA like that for half a year careful to avoid slipping the clutch, but it was in no way ideal.

Adjustment could be an issue as well, but since most modern clutches are self-adjusting(it appears the Panda fits this category) I didn't add it as a possibility in this case.

Considering the mileage of the vehicle and a lack of driving history knowledge, it might be a good idea to look at a higher quality clutch for your replacement. A stage 1 aftermarket clutch kit from a reputable brand would prevent this problem in the future if the OEM parts are indeed prone to failure.

Answer (score 0):

If the clutch has been abused by a previous owner's bad habits, it's entirely possible for the clutch to be worn out and slipping. By releasing or engaging too slowly, I can imagine the wear material on the clutch going away sooner. If the vehicle was driven in stop-and-go traffic all the time that will contribute to earlier wear, too, unlike a highway driven vehicle that has seen relatively few shifts

Comment: A car trick of any sort can damage various components real fast.